# ClassNotFoundException when trying to instantiate custom ImageView in xml

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

I've read previous questions with the same problem, however mine still persists.

I have a custom `ImageView` class which I am trying to use as my `ImageView` in my xml layout so that I am able to zoom.(got the example on stackoverflow) The problem is that in my xml when I try to use the custom `ImageView`  I get this error:[image]

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NonActivities.TouchImageView$ScaleListener
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.load(ProjectClassLoader.java:91)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:55)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:53)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at NonActivities.TouchImageView.sharedConstructing(TouchImageView.java:52)
at NonActivities.TouchImageView.<init>(TouchImageView.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

I read that you had to change the constructor to accept 2 arguments, which this class has:

```
    public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}
```

Here is the xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <NonActivities.TouchImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

any suggestions as to why this is happening?

**EDIT**
Here is the entire class(credit goes to original poster)

```
package NonActivities;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {
Matrix matrix;

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 3f;
float[] m;

int viewWidth, viewHeight;
static final int CLICK = 3;
float saveScale = 1f;
protected float origWidth, origHeight;
int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;

ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

Context context;

public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    matrix = new Matrix();
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    last.set(curr);
                    start.set(last);
                    mode = DRAG;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG) {
                        float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                        float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                        float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth,
                                origWidth * saveScale);
                        float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight,
                                origHeight * saveScale);
                        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                        fixTrans();
                        last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                    int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                    if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                        performClick();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
            }

            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            invalidate();
            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }

    });
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
    maxScale = x;
}

private class ScaleListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        float origScale = saveScale;
        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
        if (saveScale > maxScale) {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }

        if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth
                || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
                    viewHeight / 2);
        else
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                    detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

        fixTrans();
        return true;
    }
}

void fixTrans() {
    matrix.getValues(m);
    float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

    float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
    float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight
            * saveScale);

    if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
}

float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    float minTrans, maxTrans;

    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        minTrans = 0;
        maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
    } else {
        minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        maxTrans = 0;
    }

    if (trans < minTrans)
        return -trans + minTrans;
    if (trans > maxTrans)
        return -trans + maxTrans;
    return 0;
}

float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        return 0;
    }
    return delta;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    //
    // Rescales image on rotation
    //
    if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
            || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
        return;
    oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
    oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

    if (saveScale == 1) {
        // Fit to screen.
        float scale;

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0
                || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
            return;
        int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

        float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
        float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
        scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

        // Center the image
        float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight
                - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
        float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth
                - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
        redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
        redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

        origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }
    fixTrans();
}
```

}

Comment: It says something about `ScaleListener` in your error.  What is that?

Comment: that was in the example I got.

Comment: Well, that seems to be the class that isn't found.  Can you post the code for the `sharedConstructing` method?  That seems to be where your error is propagating from.

Comment: I posted the entire class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change you XML code like this:

```
<com.example.app.TouchImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

Where com.example.app is the package where is located your custom class TouchImageView.

Try changing your package like that, because when you create a new project in Android if you put like you have done it says:  `Package name must have at least two identifiers.`

Comment: the class `TouchImageView` is in my package called "NonActivities"

Comment: Try changing your package name like that, tell me if it works

Comment: that seems to have taken away the problem or at least for now. I'll try to run a few test and if it works I'll mark it as answered

Comment: Accept my answer as correct if it helps you solve your problem, and a vote up if you can, I dont know why i have received a vote down

Answer (score 1):

In your `layout` change this

```
 <NonActivities.TouchImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

to **yourpackagename** as `com.example.myapp`

```
 <com.example.myapp.TouchImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

Comment: Based on his logcat, it seems that `NonActivities` is his package name.

Comment: that is my package name

Comment: what is TouchImageView.java line number 46

Comment: @AndrewSchuster As Ultimo_m said "Package name must have at least two identifiers"

Comment: both for your answers are the same however @ultimo_m gave some additional info before. But I upvoted yours because it was also correct

Comment: @john I got little bit confused.Anyway Happy to help,Enjoy coding.